# Libtorrent 1.1 unresolved external symbol if_nametoindex

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, unresolved-external, libtorrent

I am trying to make works `libtorrent` on VS2015 with boost 1.60. I built both and trying to build example "simple_client" from `libtorrent` but unfortunately it shows me:

> unresolved external symbol if_nametoindex (broadcast_socket.obj)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

the `if_nametoindex` function is defined in iphlpapi.dll. See the documentation on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408409(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, Arvid, for reply! As I understand I need to include header file and lib for this dll. I'll try.